# Filtering text file based on values in some lines using awk

Tags: python, shell, awk, sed

I am dealing with a text file and each record in the file is separated by blank line. I want to extract the records which meats certain criteria.

For example, my text file looks like this

```
#EVM predictionEVM prediction: Mode:STANDARD S-ratio: 2.52 11043-11477 orient(-) score(1246.00)
11477   11043   single- 4   6   {SNAP_model.scaffold6_size143996-snap.2;SNAP

#EVM prediction: Mode:STANDARD S-ratio: 1.00 20968-21183 orient(+) score(432.00)
20968   21183   single+ 1   3   {GeneID_mRNA_scaffold6_size143996_6;GeneID}

#EVM prediction: Mode:STANDARD S-ratio: 1.00 21940-22362 orient(-) score(846.00)
22362   21940   single- 4   6   {GeneID_mRNA_scaffold6_size143996_7;GeneID}

#EVM prediction: Mode:STANDARD S-ratio: 12.32 33363-34677 orient(+) score(21500.00)
33363   33495   initial+    1   1   {SNAP_model.scaffold6_size143996-snap.3;SNAP},{GeneID_mRNA_scaffold6_size143996_10;GeneID},{Augustus_model.g38.t1;Augustus}
33496   33611   INTRON          {SNAP_model.scaffold6_size143996-snap.3;SNAP},{GeneID_mRNA_scaffold6_size143996_10;GeneID},{Augustus_model.g38.t1;Augustus},{ev_type:GeMoMa/ID=model.scaffold6_size143996.rna-XM_007036272.2_R0;GeMoMa}
33612   33741   internal+   2   2   {SNAP_model.scaffold6_size143996-snap.3;SNAP},{GeneID_mRNA_scaffold6_size143996_10;GeneID},{Augustus_model.g38.t1;Augustus},{ev_type:GeMoMa/ID=model.scaffold6_size143996.rna-XM_007036272.2_R0;GeMoMa}
33742   33842   INTRON          {SNAP_model.scaffold6_size143996-snap.3;SNAP},{GeneID_mRNA_scaffold6_size143996_10;GeneID},{Augustus_model.g38.t1;Augustus},{ev_type:GeMoMa/ID=model.scaffold6_size143996.rna-XM_007036272.2_R0;GeMoMa}
33843   34677   terminal+   3   3   {SNAP_model.scaffold6_size143996-snap.3;SNAP},{GeneID_mRNA_scaffold6_size143996_10;GeneID},{Augustus_model.g38.t1;Augustus}

#EVM prediction: Mode:STANDARD S-ratio: 2.41 46394-48564 orient(-) score(9677.00) noncoding_equivalent(4012.03) raw_noncoding(7194.39) offset(3182.36) 
46879   46394   terminal-   4   6   {GeneID_mRNA_scaffold6_size143996_13;GeneID}
47512   46880   INTRON          {GeneID_mRNA_scaffold6_size143996_13;GeneID}
48256   47513   internal-   4   6   {GeneID_mRNA_scaffold6_size143996_13;GeneID}
48366   48257   INTRON          {Augustus_model.g41.t1;Augustus}
48429   48367   internal-   4   6   {Augustus_model.g41.t1;Augustus}
48510   48430   INTRON          {Augustus_model.g41.t1;Augustus}
48564   48511   initial-    4   6   {Augustus_model.g41.t1;Augustus}
```

Now, I want to extract the records with score greater 1000. I want to remove second and third record which has sccore-432 `score(432.00)`and score-846 `score(846.00)`

I have written awk code

```sh
awk -F '[()]' '{if ($4 > 1000) print $0}' input.out
```

but it is giving only first line as output. i.e

```
#EVM predictionEVM prediction: Mode:STANDARD S-ratio: 2.52 11043-11477 orient(-) score(1246.00)
#EVM prediction: Mode:STANDARD S-ratio: 12.32 33363-34677 orient(+) score(21500.00)
#EVM prediction: Mode:STANDARD S-ratio: 2.41 46394-48564 orient(-) score(9677.00) noncoding_equivalent(4012.03) raw_noncoding(7194.39) offset(3182.36)
```

But I want to extract complete record corresponding to the score greater than 1000.
Please help to extract complete record

Comment: Why does this question have a `python` tag?

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** As per OP's comment, adding edited code here.

```
awk '
/^#EVM/{ found=="" }
match($0,/score\([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\)/){
  found=1
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/.*\(|)$/,"",val)
  if(val+0>1000){ print; next }
}
found
' Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
match($0,/score\([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\)/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/.*\(|)$/,"",val)
  if(val+0>1000){ print }
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                  ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/score\([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\)/){   ##Using match function to match regex of (digits DOT digits ) in current line.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)        ##Creating sub string of matched regex above and storing it to val here.
  gsub(/.*\(|)$/,"",val)               ##Globally substituting everything till ( and ) at last of line with NULL in val here.
  if(val+0>1000){ print }              ##If val is greater than 1000 then print line.
}' Input_file                          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Hii, Thanks for your help.It is working in terms of filtering based on score. But this code is giving same output as i was getting before. It is printing only the first line of each filtered record

Comment: @SanthoshHegde, could you please clarify more on this one?

Comment: There are 6 records in the above mentioned text file. Out of which I have to extract only the records with score >1000. This score value for each record is in the line starting with #. From the above example, I want extract 1st, 2nd and 3rd record. Here record means not only the line starting with #. The downstream lines till next # is belongs to previous record. But when I run the code, The filtering is happening but I am not getting complete record. I am getting only lines with # character. I want to get the downstream lines also if the score is greater than 1000.

Comment: @SanthoshHegde, If I get it correctly could you please check my EDIT code and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: I tried the edited code. It is not filtering according to score. It is giving  output same as input

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk` with an empty `RS` and `match` function:

```sh
awk -v RS= 'match($0, /score\([^)]+\)/) && substr($0, RSTART+6, RLENGTH-7)+0 > 1000 {ORS = RT; print}' file

#EVM predictionEVM prediction: Mode:STANDARD S-ratio: 2.52 11043-11477 orient(-) score(1246.00)
11477   11043   single- 4   6   {SNAP_model.scaffold6_size143996-snap.2;SNAP

#EVM prediction: Mode:STANDARD S-ratio: 12.32 33363-34677 orient(+) score(21500.00)
33363   33495   initial+    1   1   {SNAP_model.scaffold6_size143996-snap.3;SNAP},{GeneID_mRNA_scaffold6_size143996_10;GeneID},{Augustus_model.g38.t1;Augustus}
33496   33611   INTRON          {SNAP_model.scaffold6_size143996-snap.3;SNAP},{GeneID_mRNA_scaffold6_size143996_10;GeneID},{Augustus_model.g38.t1;Augustus},{ev_type:GeMoMa/ID=model.scaffold6_size143996.rna-XM_007036272.2_R0;GeMoMa}
33612   33741   internal+   2   2   {SNAP_model.scaffold6_size143996-snap.3;SNAP},{GeneID_mRNA_scaffold6_size143996_10;GeneID},{Augustus_model.g38.t1;Augustus},{ev_type:GeMoMa/ID=model.scaffold6_size143996.rna-XM_007036272.2_R0;GeMoMa}
33742   33842   INTRON          {SNAP_model.scaffold6_size143996-snap.3;SNAP},{GeneID_mRNA_scaffold6_size143996_10;GeneID},{Augustus_model.g38.t1;Augustus},{ev_type:GeMoMa/ID=model.scaffold6_size143996.rna-XM_007036272.2_R0;GeMoMa}
33843   34677   terminal+   3   3   {SNAP_model.scaffold6_size143996-snap.3;SNAP},{GeneID_mRNA_scaffold6_size143996_10;GeneID},{Augustus_model.g38.t1;Augustus}

#EVM prediction: Mode:STANDARD S-ratio: 2.41 46394-48564 orient(-) score(9677.00) noncoding_equivalent(4012.03) raw_noncoding(7194.39) offset(3182.36)
46879   46394   terminal-   4   6   {GeneID_mRNA_scaffold6_size143996_13;GeneID}
47512   46880   INTRON          {GeneID_mRNA_scaffold6_size143996_13;GeneID}
48256   47513   internal-   4   6   {GeneID_mRNA_scaffold6_size143996_13;GeneID}
48366   48257   INTRON          {Augustus_model.g41.t1;Augustus}
48429   48367   internal-   4   6   {Augustus_model.g41.t1;Augustus}
48510   48430   INTRON          {Augustus_model.g41.t1;Augustus}
48564   48511   initial-    4   6   {Augustus_model.g41.t1;Augustus}
```

A more readable version:

```sh
awk -v RS= '
match($0, /score\([^)]+\)/) && substr($0, RSTART+6, RLENGTH-7)+0 > 1000 {
   ORS = RT
   print
}' file
```

Comment: Hii, Thanks for the help. I tried the code. It is working pretty cool with the test file. But when I tried onn a original file (with 60,000 records), it is not working. Even didn't show any error also.

Comment: Answer can be based on sample data provided. If you upload any other sample for which it doesn't work then I can check it from my end.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{split($8,k,"[()]")} k[2]> 1000' RS= ORS='\n\n' input
```

When RS is set to the empty string, awk will treat a blank line as the record separater.  We set ORS to two newlines so that blank lines are retained in the output.  This solution simply splits the 8th field on the parentheses.  According to the problem description, that field is expected to be a string of the form `score(N)` (if that condition on the input is not met, some error checking should be added.)  By splitting on that filed, we get `N` in k[2], so we simply check if that value is greater than 1000.  When it is, the default rule to print the record is applied.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E '/score\([1-9][0-9]{3,}/, /^ *$/!d' file
```